# java read integers from text file

Tags: java, inputstream

I am using eclipse ; I need to read integers from a text file that may have many lines of numbers separated by space : 71 57 99 ...
I need to get these numbers as 71  and 57 ...but my code produces numbers in the range 10 to 57

```
    int size = 0;
    int[] spect = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataset.txt");
        size = is.available();
        spect = new int[size];
        for (int si = 0; si < size; si++) {
            spect[si] = (int) is.read();//   System.out.print((char)is.read() + "  ");
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may convert it to a `BufferedReader` and read and split the lines.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] strings = line.split(" ");
    for (String str : strings) {
         Integer foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
         //do what you need with the Integer
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody said there are newlines between every pair of numbers.

Comment: But it does not need to have. The question says that there is a white space between them, so I've used `line.split(" ")`. But if there are multiple lines in the input file, the `br.readLine()` in the while loop will handle.

Comment: this says bufferredreader has no constructor that takes is : inputstram

Comment: "0 71 97 99 103 113 113 114 115 131 137 196 200 202 208 214 226 227 228 240 245 299 311 311 316 327 337 339 340 341 358 408 414 424 429 436 440 442 453 455 471 507 527 537 539 542 551 554 556 566 586 622 638 640 651 653 657 664 669 679 685 735 752 753 754 756 766 777 782 782 794 848 853 865 866 867 879 885 891 893 897 956 962 978 979 980 980 990 994 996 1022 1093"

Comment: @kobosh I did not get why did you post the content of your file. Did it work with the new code I posted?

Comment: execuse me brlaranjeira  I am getting extra  lines at the end all zeros and the number of integers is 366 instead of 92

Answer (score 2):

[`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) reads single `byte` and then you are converting into `int` value, you need to read line by line using `BufferedReader` and then `split()` and `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a Scanner to do this? Scanner can take the name of the file as the parameter and can easily read out each individual number.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataset.txt");
int[] spect = new int[is.available()];
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("/dataset.txt");

for(int i = 0; fileScanner.hasNextInt(); i++){
    spect[i] = fileScanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: this is returning all zeros

Comment: I just noticed there was an error in the code. Did you catch that and fix it youself? If not it may be worth trying again.